# wordpress how to add shortcode to theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, shortcode

I installed this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easing-slider/installation/

I managed to install and configure it. I can use it in a post or page by using: [easingslider]

Now, I am currently testing with the theme Twenty Eleven. I want to replace the default header of Twenty Eleven by this one. How do I do this?

Thanks already!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can place a `do_shortcode` in your template files, i.e. in header.php:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[your-shortcode]'); ?>
```

Totally depends on how the plugin was coded though.